# Atomated transfer of log file from amazon ec2 instance to local

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, chef-infra, flume

How can I automatically transfer a log file which is present in amazon ec2 instance to my local machine. Can anyone give an idea about it. I would like to do it by a java API.

Currently I was using Chef "flume cookbook", but i was stuck at the part of automating it. And also that chef can be used in java APIs, so the process can be automated.